# Finding the inverse for two variable functions

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

so I have this function:
$$f(x,y) = (ax+by, cx+dy)$$

I was wondering how you would find the inverse for this function. I know it is defined to $$f^{-1}(x,y)=\biggl(\frac{dx-by}{ad-bc}, \frac{-cx+ay}{ad-bc}\biggr)$$ when $ad-bc\neq0$ but I have no idea how this was calculated or solved other than it being written within the solution manual of a problem that involves taking the inverse. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, finding a formula for the inverse of a 2-var function can be very very hard. For the specific case of a function like this one ("linear in each variable") we can do it with basic algebra.  Write
\begin{align}
u &= ax + by\\
v &= cx + dy.
\end{align}
The goal is then to find expressions for $x$ and $y$ just in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Multiply the top equation by $d$ and the bottom by $b$ to make the $y$ terms the same:
\begin{align}
du &= adx + bdy\\
bv &= bcx + bdy.
\end{align}
Subtract the top equation from the bottom to get
\begin{align}
du &= adx + bdy\\
bv - du &= bcx - adx = (bc - ad)x.
\end{align}
And now you can solve that last equation for $x$, getting
\begin{align}
du &= adx + bdy\\
\frac{bv - du}{bc - ad} &= x.
\end{align}
You can either plug that into the first equation and solve for $y$, or you can return to the start and multiply the top equation by $c$ and the bottom by $a$ to get
\begin{align}
cu &= acx + bcy\\
av &= acx + ady.
\end{align}
Subtract to get
\begin{align}
cu &= acx + bcy\\
av - cu  &= ady - bcy = (ad - bc)y
\end{align}
and then divide the last equation to get
\begin{align}
\frac{av - cu}{ad - bc}  &= y
\end{align}

and there are your two formula!

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is actually a linear map from $K^2$ to itself ($K$ is the base field), therefore it is represented by a $2{\times} 2$-matrix $A$. This formula stems from the following formula, valid from any square matrix $A$:
$$A\cdot\operatorname{com}(A)=(\det A)I_n,$$
where the comatrix $\,\operatorname{com}(A)$ is, by definition, the matrix of cofactors of ${\:}^{\mathrm t\mkern -5mu}A$, so
$$A^{-1}=\frac 1{\det A}\,\operatorname{com}(A).$$